# Basic Inequalities of Lebesgue Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have two very basic questions on Lebesgue integrals:

Q1) I know that if $f$ and $g$ are measurable and if $0\leq g\leq f$ on $E$, then $\int_E g\leq\int_E f$. My question is why is the condition $0\leq g$ needed? (or is it unnecessary? any counterexamples?)

Q2) What is the difference and relationship between $$\int_Ef_k\to\int_E f$$ and $$\int_E |f_k-f|\to 0$$? From what I understand, the second seems to be stronger, I can intuitively see that $f_k-f\leq|f_k-f|$ so if the second tends to zero, so should the first. Any counterexamples here that the first does not imply the second?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Q1) it is unnecessary. All you need is $g\leq f$ to have $\int f\leq \int g$.

Q2)$\int_E |f_k-f|\to 0$ means that $(f_k)$ converges to $f$ in norm $L^1$, which is stronger than $\int_Ef_k\to\int_E f$ (by triangular inequality).

Comment: @anonymus We are only assuming $f,g$ are measurable, so $\int f, \int g $ may not be well defined. The assumption $0\le g \le f$ assures the integrals are well defined.

Comment: @zhw. just curious even if the integrals are negative infinity /infinity can't we say $-\infty\leq\infty$?

Comment: If we only know $f$ is measurable, then what does $\int f$ mean?

Comment: @zhw. Based on my (limited) understanding if $f$ is only measurable then $\int f$ could possibly be infinite? Is that correct?

Comment: What would $\int_\mathbb R \cos x \, dx $ equal?

Comment: @zhw. I see, the lebesgue integral is undefined since it is infinity minus infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The assumption $0\le g$ assures that both integrals exist (in $[0,\infty]$).
2. $f_k-f\le |f_k-f|$ doesn't help you. But $|\int f_k - \int f| = |\int (f_k  -f)|  \le \int|f_k-f|$ does help. Useful example: Let $f_k(x) = \sin (kx), f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1].$

Comment: Nice example for $\sin(kx)$